# Reading exception from try catch when exception type not specified

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

In cases when you use a try catch block as such.

```
try {
    //Do my work!
} 
catch 
{
    //Handle my exception
}
```

Is there some way to refer to the exception object in the catch block?

ie:

```
try {
    //Do my work!
} 
catch 
{
    //Handle my exception
    MyUndefinedExceptionObject.Message ????
}
```

> EDIT: I don't think I was clear
>   enough. I am aware of how one would
>   typically catch exceptions using a try
>   catch block. What I am wondering is
>   given you have the ability to not
>   specify a type for your exception yet
>   declare the block is there still some
>   way of retrieving the exception object
>   in such cases? Judging by your answers
>   however I assume there isn't?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to catch the exception type you care about. When you do, you'll have access to all the properties of that exception.

```
try
{
    //Do my work!
} 
catch (MyExceptionType e)
{
   string s = e.Message;
}
```

Here's a [reference in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx), to get up to speed.

Regarding your edit: no there is no way to access the thrown exception unless the exception is explicitly specified in your catch statement.

Comment: I'm curious about your use case, though, Maxim. Care to elaborate?

Comment: No use case. Just curiosity about the language structure and specifications.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, like this:

```
try 
{
    //Do my work!
} 
catch (mySpecificException myEx)
{
    //Handle my exception
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Handle my exception
}
```

(Most specific to least specific)

Answer (score 2):

No.

Using the bare `catch` indicates that you do not care about the actual exception otherwise, why not use

```
catch (System.Exception ex)
```

to catch any exception? Of course, you should only catch exceptions you will handle.

Answer (score 1):

You need to indicate the specific type of exception that you are catching, and assign that to a variable.

Do that using this syntax instead:

```
try 
{
    // Do work
}
catch (MyUndefinedExceptionObject ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

You can also include *multiple* catch blocks with the type of exception altered accordingly. However, remember that you should always order them from *most* derived to *least* derived, ending with the base class for all exceptions, `System.Exception`.

You also should generally refrain from catching `System.Exception`, instead preferring *only* to catch the derived exceptions that you can handle in the `catch` block and that won't corrupt your program's state. Catching `System.Exception` class is a bad idea because you'll also catch exceptions that you won't be able to handle, like an `OutOfMemoryException` or a `StackOverflowException`.

Microsoft has a helpful article on best practices here: [Best Practices for Handling Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts.aspx)